# Where I can find the CD version of Stan Wagon - "Mathematica in action" 3rd ed. book?

Tags: reference-request

I've just started my license and I need the code to focus on implementing my programs. I can't make the code in the book run. Can anyone help?

Comment: Relevant user: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2902/stan-wagon

Comment: http://extras.springer.com/2010/978-0-387-75366-9

Comment: Thanks a lot for extras.springer.com/2010/978-0-387-75366-9 .

Answer (score 10):

Turning kjo's comment into an answer, the code is available from the publisher [here](http://extras.springer.com/2010/978-0-387-75366-9).