# Mathematica in Action (Wagon) — code to generate a great circle is giving error

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

I have code from Stan Wagon's *Mathematica in Action*, Chapter 17 (Great Circle Problem), but when I try to run it, it does not work. I have *Mathematica* 10. The code that does not run is shown below. Do I need some special library in order to run this code?

```
{g, g3D} = 
  RandomGreatCircleGraph[4, 
    Include3DPlot -> True, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5], Yellow}];
g3D

SeedRandom[11]; 
{g, g3D} = 
  RandomGreatCircleGraph[4, 
    Include3DPlot -> True, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5], Yellow}];

Show[g3D, ViewAngle -> 0.3, ImageSize -> 200]
```

Comment: When did you define `RandomGreatCircleGraph`?  Is that a function in the book?

Comment: yes, that is a function in the book. This function is in read, and the author claims that and I do not know what is that, can you help me?: This disk contains  some extra code used to generate the figures exactly as they appear in the book (for example, the COA group has the code for the "Chapter Opening Art"). That extra code appears in red. More important, several of the chapters rely on packages of code or other extra code. Such code appears at the top of each chapter in a group called "Code for Electronic Supplement".

Comment: For those who want to see the code in the book, see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87284).

Comment: Any red you're seeing is quite likely due to shadowing, in that you tried to execute the example before executing the notebook's definitions, which are in a separate context. Restart *Mathematica*, execute *everything* within the "Code for Electronic Supplement" cell, and try again.

Comment: Hi, The code worked, I run this Electronic supplement code and everything worked. You saved my life. Thank you. Do you now how can I calculate the chromatic number for the great circle?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Comments are not the place to ask further questions. Please post a new question concerning "how can I calculate the chromatic number for the great circle?"

Comment: The conjecture that all those great circle graphs are 3-colorable is now a quite famous conjecture. It is equivalent to some other nice problems. The only partial result I know is a proof I worked out that one can always 3-color the northern hemisphere together with the equator (assumed to be one of the great circles).

Comment: Hi Stan, do you have an article about this conjecture? I am PhD student in Computer Science and I need to present a conjecture about that.

Comment: No, I do not. I worked a bit on that result I mentioned about half spheres but did not publish it. I Streinu at Smith College (CS) has a paper with an equivalent  version of the same problem. That is mentioned in my book. That paper is                S. Felsner, F. Hurtado, M. Noy, and I. Streinu, Hamiltonicity and colorings of arrangement graphs, Discrete Applied Mathematics 154 (2006) 2470-2483.  And Joe O'Rourke has included this problem on a list of his of important open problems in geometry.