# how do I actually see the code on the cd version of stan wagon's mathematica in action 3rd ed?

Tags: notebooks, reference-request

It was pointed out in   [Where I can find the CD version of Stan Wagon - "Mathematica in action" 3rd ed. book?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87284/where-i-can-find-the-cd-version-of-stan-wagon-mathematica-in-action-3rd-ed)
that the code for Wagon's book is available at http://extras.springer.com/2010/978-0-387-75366-9

I have downloaded all the notebooks from that site, but when I click on any of them, it will open up in Mathematica, but all I see is the section headings. For example when I open the notebook for chapter 1 I get the following

[image]

I am using Mathematica 11.1.1.0 on mac os x. Is there some trick that I need to employ to actually see the code?

Comment: To you see those brackets with the arrow pointing down at the right of the screen? Try to double click on them; they shoul expand...

Comment: @Henrik, thanks this does indeed work, but with one caveat -- namely you must right double click, rather than the usual left double click.

Comment: Oh? For me it's a left double click...

Comment: @Henrik, maybe the OS makes a difference. I'm on Mac OS X, what are you running on?

Comment: Also macOS. But maybe I made some nonstandard system setting years ago. Doesn't matter, though.